# Issue with Vega data URL loading - Opensearch Dashboard

Tags: vega, opensearch-dashboards

I have a new installation of Opensearch with Opensearch Dashboard. I have Vega on it and I'm trying to reproduce the example below: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/force-directed-layout I copied the contents of the data/miserables.json file to my folder where the Vega script is running. And when trying to execute it returns the error: Loading failed

The strangest thing is that any url I put in the url field returns the same error. Both local files and public files.

Does anyone have any idea what I missed?

I'm trying to load a json file from a URL in Vega using a view in Opensearch Dashboard.

Error: JSON file does not load Show: Loading failed data/diagram.json

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "node-data",
      "url": "data/diagram.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "nodes"}
    },
    {
      "name": "link-data",
      "url": "data/diagram.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "links"}
    }
  ],
```

Estou tentando reproduzir este exemplo em meu painel Opensearch: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/force-directed-layout